# change boot sequence on dell inspiron 13

Tags: boot, uefi, dell

i have an external HDD with ubuntu installed, and i cannot make my Dell Inspiron 13 5000 (windows 10 pre-installed) boot from it.

i go to BIOS, switch safe boot off, check EFI ROM, but then Legacy option is not still allowed and i have (?) to chose a file to define a boot sequence. it used to be a lot simpler.

if anybody can help, i'll be thankful.

regards,
nikos

Comment: There might be a separate setting that controls whether you can boot from USB drives.

Comment: in fact the problem solved itself without passing through BIOS : i hit  F12 for boot options with my HDD connected, made my way through the options to boot from the external HDD. the second time i booted I hit again F12 and chose "external USB device",  and the third time it booted automatically on the external HDD.

(If the moderators think the question is redundant they can erase it)